# After trying to update, Ubuntu fails booting

Tags: boot, kernel, updates

I tried to update Ubuntu but the system seems not to work any longer.
Shutting the system down also seems not possible. So I pressed the power button hoping to restart and what I was afraid of happened: the system does not boot any more.

```
Target file system doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash
[3.456425] Kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

[3.456425]
[3.4556471] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: sh Not Tainted 3.13.0-92-gerneric #139-Ubuntu
[3.4565101]Hardware name: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 745
etc...

Call Trace
dump_stack
panic
not exit
do_group_exit
SyS_exit_group
system_all_fastpath
```

What should I do?